# Проблема с модальными окнами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем здравствуйте! Недавно начал изучать основу вёрстки. Верстал по макету и столкнулся с двумя проблемами.

[image: Ссылка "Смотреть работу"]

- На скриншоте видно, что подчёркивание точками обозначено шире надписи "Смотреть работу". Как можно выровнить подчёркивание, чтоб оно шло ровно по ширине текста?
- Проблема с модальными окнами. При нажатии на ссылку "Смотреть работу" должно выходить модальное окно с изображением и описанием.

[image: Модальное окно]

Но у меня выходит только окно с одной надписью "Описание проекта" больше ничего.

P.S: В самом видео, по которому делал вёрстку, данных проблем не возникало, всё работало чётко и плавно. Также автор данного видео оставил ссылку для загрузки файла с данной вёрсткой, который сверстал на видео. И там также присутствуют эти же проблемы, хотя на видео, как я уже оговаривал, всё хорошо работает. В чём может быть проблема?

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
html {
 font-size: 10px;
}
a:active, a:visited, a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}
.wrapper {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.main {
 position: relative;
 display:table;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #000 url(../img/main-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}
.main-overlay {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.main h1 {
 margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 4.8rem;
}
.main p {
 font-size: 3rem;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.main-header {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
.main-line {
 width: 200px;
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.main-down {
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 4;
 bottom: 2rem;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 2rem;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 line-height: 50px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -25px;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.main-down:hover {
 color: #fff;
 border-color: #fff;
}
/* Секция с портфолио */
.portfolio {
 padding: 10rem 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
.section-header {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 3.6rem;
 margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
.portfolio img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 360px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 29px 0px rgba(87, 92, 97, 0.54);
}
.portfolio a {
 display: block;
 margin: 2rem auto 6rem;
 color: #333;
 width: 17rem;
 border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.portfolio a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #333;
}
/* Секция - подвал (footer) */
.footer {
 background-color: #646464;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3rem 0;
}
.footer strong {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 2.4rem;
}
.social-links {
 margin-top: 1rem;
}
.social-links a {
 width: 5rem;
 height: 5rem;
 line-height: 5rem;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
 border: solid 1px #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-left: 1rem;
 margin-right: 1rem;
 font-size: 2rem;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.social-links a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #646464;
}
.offer-btn {
 display: block;
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 200px;
 margin: 1rem auto;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 padding-top: 1rem;
 padding-bottom: 1rem;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 100px;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.offer-btn:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #646464;
}
.modal img {
 width: 100%;
}
.modal-title {
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 2rem;
}
.close {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 font-size: 2.5rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: 2rem;
 top: 1rem;
}
.modal-btn {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #333;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.modal-btn:hover {
 background-color: #333;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- meta для социальных сетей -->
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Кази Рустамов - верстка сайтов на HTML и CSS">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Закажите разработку сайта без посредников от 5 990 рублей">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Портфолио верстальщика">
    <meta property="article:author" content="Кази Рустамов">
    <!-- Заголовок сайта -->
    <title>Кази Рустамов - Портфолио</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello-embedded.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Фавиконка -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main-overlay"></div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main-header">
        <h1>Кази Рустамов</h1>
        <div class="main-line"></div>
        <p>Верстка на HTML и CSS <br> Разработка сайтов под ключ</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <a class="main-down" href="#"><i class="icon-down"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="portfolio">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="section-header">Портфолио</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="portfolio-block">
              <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="Работа №1">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-1' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="portfolio-block">
              <img src="img/portfolio/2.jpg" alt="Работа №2">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-2' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="portfolio-block">
              <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" alt="Работа №3">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-work='work-3' href="#work">Смотреть работу</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <strong>Кази Рустамов</strong>
              <p>Разработка сайтов <br> под ключ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <strong>Подпишитесь</strong>
              <div class="social-links">
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-vk"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <strong>Напишите мне</strong>
              <a href="https://vk.me/rustamov_17" target="_blank" class="offer-btn">Заказать сайт</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Всплывающие окна -->
<div class="modal fade" id="work" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Описание проекта</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var link = $('a[data-toggle="modal"]');
        link.on('click', function(event) {
          var work = $(this).link.attr('data-work');
          var modal = $('.modal');
          modal.find('.modal-body').load(work+'.html');
      });
     });   
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё потому что в видео в котором ты смотришь, он использует функцию `load` в JQuery котором загрузка контента модального окна идет с отдельного `.html` файла.

А он работает только если запущен сервер, и локально он работать не будет. Запусти какой нибудь локальный сервер и всё заработает.

А насчет ссылок, сделай ссылку строчно-блочной, и обводка будет точно по размеру самого текста.

Comment: Пожалуйста) Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: Метод jQuery `load` абсолютно без проблем загрузит указанный файл локально, без всяких серверов. Минусовать не буду, но если каких-то знаний не достаточно, то компенсируйте их хотя бы экспериментальным путем.